# How to check whether current digest has finished as "clean" and will not trigger another digest loop

Tags: angularjs

The subject stands for the question itself, is there a way in angular to check whether current digest cycle has been completed as the last one and the model has been settled and current digest cycle itself will not trigger another digest cycle

I understand that the digest cycle can be triggered by user code or as a result of user's interaction with the browser. In any way angular knows when to stop digesting deeper and deeper.

Comment: angular knows internally when to stop of course.... but why do you need to know? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Our project automation testers create auto-tests via Silenium, Silenium analyses UI right after the page is loaded, but not when UI is ready for that kind of checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `scope.$$postDigest` or `$timeout(..., 0, false)`.

[Here is](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/choroshin/2014/04/08/angularjs-postdigest-vs-timeout-when-dom-update-is-needed/) a good summary on both methods.